# How to save prompt input into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

I`m having some issue with Javascript.
We just started to study it a couple weeks ago and I have to do a work for class:

Need to do a prompt. get 10 numbers input (10 grades) from the user.
put the numbers into an array and then do some functions with it.

My question is how do I save the input in the array?
We learned about all the loops already. Tried to search online but didn`t found an answer.

I would love if somebody could explain how I do it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: how are the numbers split up? is it 10 different numbers in the input separated by commas or 10 different inputs?

Comment: How about you take your current markup and code and put it into a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 7):

Just try to ask them to input their numbers or grade, separated by a comma and then you can split on it.

```
var arr = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",")
```

Or, ask `prompt` ten times

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   arr.push(prompt("Enter a number");
```

If you want them to be numbers, just prefix `prompt` with `+`, so it becomes a number(provided they're actual numbers) or just do

```
arr = arr.map(Number);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the explanations in comments:

```js
var arr = [];                               // define our array

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {              // loop 10 times
  arr.push(prompt('Enter grade ' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
}

alert('Full array: ' + arr.join(', '));     // alert the results
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 10;

var i = 0;     // Loop iterator
var userInput; // Input from user
sum = 0; //initialise sum

// Collect inputs
for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; i++)
{   userInput = parseInt(prompt('Enter input '+(i+1)+' of '+NUMBER_OF_INPUTS));
    sum += userInput;
    sum /= NUMBER_OF_INPUTS;
}

// Output the average
alert('Average grade: '+ sum.toFixed(2)); //the .toFixed sets it to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    var grades = [];
    var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            grades.push(Number(prompt("Enter your grades:" + (i + 1), "0-100")));
        }
    document.write("Your grades: " + grades);
</script>
```

Ok so I made this one.
The user can enter 10 different numbers to the array and I can display them.
Now - I need to caculate the avarage of the numbers and get the highest number.

I would like to have some help withj it, how can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  function myfunction() {
    let arr = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      arr.push(prompt());
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    console.log(arr);
  }
  myfunction();
```

Comment: You can avoid the second loop by moving `parseInt()` bit into the first one.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.