# add array together, display sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

What i am trying to do is take the user input which is numbers then add those numbers together and display the sum.

I have an array, I have the sum of the array. Now I need to display only the sum. It seems my loop is outputting all the numbers in the array.

```
function hello(){


var arr = [];                               // define our array

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {              // loop 10 times
  arr.push(prompt('Enter number' + (i+1))); // push the value into the array
}

alert('Full array: ' + arr.join(', '));    // alert the result`

var total = 0;
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var number = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
  total += number;
  console.log(total);

// gets the last element in arr[] array //does not give answer
var totalArr = arr[i][arr[i].length-1]; 
}

console.log(totalArr);
```

Comment: What's the actual code that outputs the answer?

Comment: var total = 0;
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var number = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
  total += number;
    // console.log(total);

Comment: Is this a dupe of your previous question? Code in comments is illegible, are you claiming if you uncomment the line that prints out `total` it's a concatenated string?

Comment: Yes it is a dupe. Im new to stack and i felt my thread was in the grave yard.
Var total arr at end only prints out the last user input in array not the for loop prints out all the elements in array together. Which is not what i need. i need the last element of  the sum frokm the for loop.
I cleaned up the code as well.

Comment: In general dupes aren't a good idea. When you update a previous question its visibility is bumped.

Comment: totalArr has nothing to do with a total, not really sure what you're trying to do with that-you're trying to access a specific character in the input array. The running total is in... Well, total. I'm finding it difficult to believe it is an ongoing string concatenation.

Comment: I had no idea dupes get pushed to top of list when commented on. I will head this in mind in the future. FluffyKitten this is most def a dupe for Can't add contents of array up. As explained here in the comments.

If anyone interested the answer was submitted by doug testing bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want just the total output at the end then you need to log total to the console after the loop. Based on my understanding of what you want to do I think something like the following is all that's needed...

```
function hello() {
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr.push(prompt('Enter number' + (i+1)));
    }

    var total = 0;

    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var number = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
        total += number;
    }

    console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, doug Testing this is exactly the answer I was looking for. You hit the nail on the head with this one.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please click the tick under the up/down arrows to the left so people know this question has the answer you were looking for. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I swear I'll learn how to use this site eventually lol. Cheers