# Adding prompts to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, average, prompt

I'm busy with a task that requires me to ask the user to keep entering random numbers until the number is "-1". After that I would have to get the average of all the numbers entered excluding the "-1". I've gotten this far with it:

```
var userNumbers;
while (userNumbers !== "-1") {
    userNumbers = prompt("Enter a number");
}
numbersArray = [userNumbers];
console.log(numbersArray);
```

Comment: It stands to reason that you'll need to store each entered value.... see: [Javascript - How to save prompt input into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252888/javascript-how-to-save-prompt-input-into-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Store all numbers
const numbers = [];

let userNumber;
for(;;){
    userNumber = prompt("Enter a number");
    if(userNumber === '-1') { break; }
    numbers.push(userNumber);
}

// Calculate average
let sum = 0;
let avg = 0;

numbers.forEach((value) => sum += value);

avg = sum / numbers.length
```